# Redirecting to a page without reloading

Tags: url, redirect, angularjs, reload

I've got an Angular.js app that follows quite closely the default seed app:

**app.js**

```
angular.module('wegush', ['wegush.filters', 'wegush.services', 'wegush.directives', 'wegush.controllers', 'wegush.models', 'notifierModule'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'home', controller: 'HomeController' });
        $routeProvider.when('/login', { templateUrl: 'login', controller: 'LoginController' });
        $routeProvider.when('/register', { templateUrl: 'register', controller: 'RegisterController' });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }])
```

**index.html**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/register">Register</a></li>
</ul>

<div ng-view></div>
```

In one of the services, I'm using the `$location` service to redirect the user to a given page:

```
$location.path('/');
```

However, when I do this it reloads the whole application instead of simply displaying the relevant view inside `ng-view` (like it does when I click on one of the menu links above).

So is there any trick to make `$location` show the correct view but without reloading the page?

Comment: When you say "reload the whole application", do you mean the entire page is refreshed and the angular libraries are reloaded and the entire app is bootstrapped?